# Silverstripe GridField dataFieldByName Error

Tags: silverstripe-4

I am trying to add a simple `GridField` to my Silverstripe CMS, containing only `HTMLEditorFields`. I am using the `GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor`. When I click "Add Section", I get an internal server error. Then if I refresh the page, I get the following error:

`Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Object->__call(): the method 'dataFieldByName' does not exist on 'SilverStripe\Forms\HTMLEditor\HTMLEditorField'`

I have no clue what is causing this. Does anybody know why this is happening?

Here is the code in my `Page.php`:

```
<?php

namespace {

    use SilverStripe\CMS\Model\SiteTree;
    use Silverstripe\Forms\CheckboxField;
    use Silverstripe\Forms\FieldGroup;
    use Silverstripe\Forms\HTMLEditor\HTMLEditorField;
    use SilverStripe\Forms\GridField\GridField;
    use SilverStripe\Forms\GridField\GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor;
    use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;

    class Section extends DataObject {
        private static $db = [
            'SectionContent' => 'HTMLText'
        ];

        private static $has_one = [
            'Page' => Page::class
        ];

        public function getCMSFields() {
            return HTMLEditorField::create('SectionContent');
        }
    }

    class Page extends SiteTree {
        private static $db = [
            'IncludeSections' => 'Boolean'
        ];

        private static $has_many = [
            'Sections' => Section::class
        ];

        public function getCMSFields() {
            $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

            $fields->addFieldToTab(
                'Root.Main',
                FieldGroup::create(
                    CheckboxField::create("IncludeSections")
                ), 'Content'
            );

            if ($this->IncludeSections) {
                $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main',
                   $grid = GridField::create(
                       'Sections',
                       'Sections in this page. Seperated by boxes.',
                       $this->Sections(),
                       GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create()
                   )
                );
            }

            return $fields;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the answer to my question at https://forum.silverstripe.org/t/gridfield-datafieldbyname-error/2528.

for my `getCMSFields` function in the `Section` class, I needed to return a `FieldList` rather than a single field. To do this, I changed the function to be as follows:

```
public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', HTMLEditorField::create('SectionContent'));

    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm at least in your example code you are missing a closing `)` parenthesis in your `addFieldToTab` function call.

```
$fields->addFieldToTab(
        'Root.Main',
        FieldGroup::create(
            CheckboxField::create("IncludeSections"),
            'Content'
        ); // Should be one `)` before this.
```

Fixed:

```
$fields->addFieldToTab(
        'Root.Main',
        FieldGroup::create(
            CheckboxField::create("IncludeSections"),
            'Content'
        )
   );
```

---

Also if you get exceptions after fixing that, the issue might be related to what you pass as the second argument to FieldGroup's constructor.

The documentation:

```
/**
     * Create a new field group.
     *
     * Accepts any number of arguments.
     *
     * @param mixed $titleOrField Either the field title, list of fields, or first field
     * @param mixed ...$otherFields Subsequent fields or field list (if passing in title to $titleOrField)
     */
    public function __construct($titleOrField = null, $otherFields = null) {...}
```

It might be worth a try to pass the form field instance. (not tested)

```
FieldGroup::create(
    CheckboxField::create("IncludeSections"),
    $fields->dataFieldByName('Content')
)
```

Comment: That syntax error is not in my original code, it was a mistake made when I removed unnecessary code. In response to your second idea, I think my syntax error tripped you up because it's not 'Content' that I am passing to the `FieldGroup`, I am passing `'Content'` to the `addFieldToTab` function. In my original code I have multiple fields in the `FieldGroup`, but I left them out. The full snippet of code can be seen at https://forum.silverstripe.org/t/gridfield-datafieldbyname-error/2528